# apply datepicker with bottom sheet vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm newly using vuetify. I want to apply datepicker with bottom sheet. When user focus the input field, the calendar will open up from bottom. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code for your component.

```
<template>
 <div class="text-xs-center">
  <v-bottom-sheet v-model="sheet">
   <v-text-field
     slot="activator"
     name="date"
     label="Date"
     id="date"
     v-model="date"
    ></v-text-field>
   <v-date-picker autosave style="" v-model="date"></v-date-picker>
  </v-bottom-sheet>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
       date:'',
       sheet:null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
<style>
  .dialog{
    background:white;
    justify-content:center; 
    display:flex
  }
</style>
```

please let me know if you need anything :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured it out. But i have another question. I am looking for ios type datepicker for vuejs component. Can you help me out?